# Ruby mkdir returns 0

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script which sets up a directory which I need some other methods to use to store files.  So, I need to be able to pass the directory as a string to some other methods:

**To create the directory**

```
 results_dir = Dir.mkdir("/results/#{Time.now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S')}")
```

The problem is that `results_dir` returns `0`, not the string I would expect for the directory that was made: "/results/01-18-2016_14:58:38"

So, when I try to pass this to another method (i.e. `my_method(var1, var2, results_dir)`, it's reading it as:

```
 0/the_file_i_create
```

How can I pass the actual directory path to my methods?

Comment: Just save that directory name as a string before passing it into `mkdir`. As you said, it returns an integer. There is no way around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you expect `Dir.mkdir` to return the directory name, since [the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Dir.html#method-c-mkdir) explicitly say that `Dir.mkdir` returns `0`:

> #### mkdir( string [, integer] ) → 0

If you need the name of the directory you're creating, put it in a variable before you call `Dir.mkdir`:

```
results_dir = "/results/#{Time.now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S')}"
Dir.mkdir(results_dir)

puts results_dir # => /results/01-18-2016_14:58:38
```

P.S. Avoid using colons (`:`) in file and directory names. It can cause issues on some systems, including OS X and Windows.